# While adding a arrayJson in document context array is coming with empty json

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a json similar to:

```
JSONObject jsonToReplace =new JSONObject({"country":"India", 
"city":[{"cityName":"city1", "temprature":30},{"cityName":"city2", "temprature":40}]});
```

Now I have another value:

```
JSONArray newcity = new JSONArray("[{"cityName":"city3", "temprature":20},{"cityName":"city4", "temprature":20}]");
```

I am using `com.jayway.jsonpath.DocumentContext` to replace the value.

```
doc.set("city", newcity);
```

In response, I am getting

```
{"country":"India", 
"city":[{},{}]}
```

expected

```
{"country":"India", 
"city":[{"cityName":"city3", "temprature":20},{"cityName":"city4", "temprature":20}]}

DocumentContext doc = JsonPath.parse(JsonToModify);

doc.set("city", newcity);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the definition of newcity.
you are using double quotes inside double quotes, which is not clearly understood.
**use single quotes in double quotes** and you will be good to go.

```
 JSONArray newcity = new JSONArray("[{'cityName':'city3', 'temprature':20},{'cityName':'city4', 'temprature':20}]");
```